# Crash when posting NSNotification after In-App Purchase

Tags: objective-c, nsnotification

I am very familiar with notifications but I get a crash without any reason, after using the In-App Purchase (I doubt that it relates to it anyway).

So when the user is done purchasing,this function is being called :

```
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:productIdentifier userInfo:nil];

    // i get the crash here when trying to post the notification.
 }
```

Now ,the main scene that has the observer, is setted on start with :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
```

Is it because the object set to nil on the observer? what should it be ?

Comment: What is the error message displayed?

Comment: nothing. its one of this crashes that shows me assembler code.. with no explanation .

Comment: Is IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification a valid NSString?

Comment: Did you try setting an exception Breakpoint? So one that stops on Throw of every exception?

Comment: yes, i have just checked that nsstring. its ok.

Comment: is it because the nil object on the observer ??

Comment: Did you try setting an exception Breakpoint? So one that stops on Throw of every exception? Try it without adding the observer so just posting a notification for nobody

Comment: i get on the crash this :CFXNotificationPost. what is that ?

Comment: oh wait !! do i have to remove the observer each time i leave the main scene? because i think i set him a few times before the notification..

Comment: Sure be sure just to observe on existing Objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could occur because you have an nil object as an `NSNotification observer`.

It is often good remove self from the NSNotificationCenter's observer list when the object deallocates.

Add this

```
- (void) dealloc  {
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

in all classes that is an observer for notifications. (Note that there might be other places that you want to remove the observer. E.g. in viewDidDisappear)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the Info into the userInfo like this:

```
- (void)provideContentForProductIdentifier:(NSString *)productIdentifier
{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:productIdentifier];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil userInfo:@{@"identifier": productIdentifier}];

    // i get the crash here when trying to post the notification.
 }
```

Then you can  observe the NSNotification with

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(productPurchased:) name:IAPHelperProductPurchasedNotification object:nil];
```

In `-(void) productPurchased:(NSNotification*)notification` you can get the info back:

```
-(void) productPurchased:(NSNotification*)notification {
   NSString *productIdentifier = [notification.userInfo valueForKey:@"identifier"];
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. the problem was because i didnt remove the observer.